# Avoid coinciding lines and markers in pyplot

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I have two problems which are based on a similar fact. If I use Matplotlib to plot lines which happen to lie on one another partly in that specific area only one of them is shown.

Example one

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2],[1,1],'r-')
plt.plot([1.5,3],[1,1],'b-')
plt.show()
```

Example two

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0.5,3],[0,0],'b-',marker='o')
ax = gca()
ax.set_xlim(0.4)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data',0))
plt.show()
```

I would like to have Matplotlib to plot them 1 px apart, so that one could see both lines, if that is anyhow possible.

The second thing is the same for markers. I would like matplotlib to set to markers, which have to be drawn to the same spot in the euclidean space to be drawn blow each other, because else they are barely visible.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem, please accept it (big gray checkbox on the left)

Comment: No I found none of the answers satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your data by a small amount is really dicey (and by dicey, I mean unethical) as you are opaquely changing your data.  If you are going to shift the data, you should shift by large amount so it is obvious.

A better solution is to use dashed lines, ex:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2],[1,1],'r-')
plt.plot([1.5,3],[1,1],'b--')
plt.show()
```

which gives you a dashed blue line on top of a solid red line ([line style example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/line_styles.html)).  In conjunction with `markevery` ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot)) you can spread the marked points out along the lines.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a function to offset all of the data points by a small value and plot them like so.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def offsetPlot(ax,x,y,*args,**kwargs):
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    offset = (ylim[1]-ylim[0])/125
    return [ax.plot(x,[q+offset for q in y],*args,**kwargs)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)    
    ax.set_ylim((0,1.25))
    ax.plot([1,2],[1,1],'r-')
    offsetPlot(ax,[1.5,3],[1,1],color='b',linestyle='-') #'b-' is also a valid argument
    plt.show()
```